# What kind of output is on this PID Controller

Tags: voltage, rs232, output, pid-controller

I have a [Altec PC410 PID controller](http://www.altec.cc/downloadfile/pc900_en.pdf) with 2 outputs purchased from eBay. However the exact model number is not known.

On top of the controller is a diagram showing how the 2 ouputs are different. Is it possible to identify what kind of outputs this unit has?

This PID controller will be used to drive an SSR.

**Possible Outputs**

[image]

**Actual device**

[image]

Comment: First step, open it up and look (share pictures if uncertain) the wiring label implies relay outputs but may be generic as mentioned below.

Comment: Some of these type of units can be soft configured to any output type even if not supported by the PCB.  On some a simple wire link to replace a relay output may let you use it to drive a SSR instead of having the relay outputs, having a known correct unit to compare against is almost essential before making modifications though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like OUT1 is a SPDT relay contact and OUT2 is a SPST relay output.

SPDT means single pole double throw i.e. a changeover relay contact

SPST means single pole signle throw i.e. a normally open relay contact.

Both relay contacts can be presumed to be able to work with a 250VAC AC connected load at up to 3 amps but, without the exact model number and technical manual this is still a bit of an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible- the label is generic and the table refers to portions of the part number.

Either find the part number or test it. If you assume it's a contact and connect it as such (and it's not) you'll probably blow the **** out of it and may endanger yourself in the process. At a minimum mains voltage will be coming out of the sensor terminals.